# How to do the expansion of variable in shell script?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, ksh

I hava a column in database which contains the following data:

```
sql_proc|test_sql.sql|/home/Desktop/myfile.txt|$IMP_FILES/myFolder|convert
```

I have fetched this into a variable and I have used the `cut` command with `"|"` as delimiter and saved each field in a different variable. Now let's consider `VAR4` holds 4th field, i.e `$IMP_FILES/myFolder`. `$IMP_FILES` is an environment variable with value `/home/OffFiles/Module`.

How can I use `VAR4` in order to get `/home/OffFiles/Module/myFolder`?

Comment: @JohnSmith no that's different. op needs `path=\`bash -c "echo '$var4'"\`` or `path=\`eval echo $var4\``

Comment: Is the environment variable name fixed or does it vary — is it always `$IMP_FILES` or can it be `$HOME` and `$UMBRELLA` etc in other lines.

Comment: @JohnSmith Thanks, that thread helped. and  thank you all for the help, I have decided to use eval it works good for me.

Comment: @HuStmpHrrr  `bash -c "echo '$var4'"` wont expand `$IMP_FILES` You need double quote around `$var4` and that makes it as insecure as eval.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `bash -c`:

```
newvar="$(bash -c "echo $var")"
```

Using `eval`:

```
newvar="$(eval "echo $var")"
```

Example:

```
#!/bin/bash
var='$PATH'
echo "$var" #This will show that $var contains the string $PATH literally

#Using bash -c
newvar="$(bash -c "echo "$var"")"
echo "$newvar"

#using eval
newvar="$(eval "echo "$var"")"
echo "$newvar"
```

It will print the environment variable paths twice.

Answer (score 0):

The insecure solution is to use `eval`:

```
eval echo "$VAR4"
```

Don't do this, though, imagine what happens when `VAR4='|rm -rf /'`!

You can use associative array instead of environment variables.

```
#!/bin/bash
declare -A dict
dict[IMP_FILES]=/home/OffFiles/Module
# ...

VAR4='$IMP_FILES/myFolder'
while [[ $VAR4 =~ \$([_A-Z]+) ]] ; do
    key=${BASH_REMATCH[1]}
    VAR4=${VAR4/\$$key/${dict[$key]}}
done
echo "$VAR4"
```

Note that the solution is recursive, i.e. it can grow the string endlessly if the dictionary contains a key in a value. I'd drop shell and move to Perl, which can handle similar problems more easily.

Comment: using bash itself sounds safe enough. `bash -c "echo '|echo abc'"` prints the text honestly.

Comment: @HuStmpHrrr: OK, try `VAR4=\'\|rm\ -rf\ /\'`